# Returning an array of integers with 1000 elements

Tags: java

> Write a function that returns an array of integers with 1000 elements
>   containing the values 1 to 1000 in random order. No number can be
>   repeated or omitted.Your answer should show good programming style,
>   technique and attention to accuracy and performance.
>
> Hint: use Random rnd=new Random() to create a new instance of the
>   random number generator and rnd.Next(1,1000) to get a random integer
>   value between 1 and 1000. No other .Net framework classes should be
>   needed outside of the intrinsic data types (i.e. DO NOT use
>   collections).

For that I have developed the following code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Domain {

public int[] randomIntArray(int size) {

    Random random = new Random();
    int intArrayHolder[] = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < intArrayHolder.length; i++) {

        boolean isDuplicate = false;

        /*
         * because random.nextInt(int var) return between 0 and given-no and
         * we do not want 0. So size +1 and later in program, we do not
         * assign 0 to the intArrayHolder.
         */

        int randomNextInt = random.nextInt(size + 1);

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (intArrayHolder[j] == randomNextInt) {

                isDuplicate = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ((!isDuplicate) && (randomNextInt != 0)) {
            intArrayHolder[i] = randomNextInt;
        } else {

            i--;

        }

    }

    return intArrayHolder;
}

}
```

JUnit test class:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class DomainJunitTest {

Domain domain = null;
int arraySize = 0;

@Before
public void initialize() throws Exception {
    domain = new Domain();
    arraySize = 1000;
}

@Test
public void randomIntArray_size_check() {

    int intArrayHolder[] = domain.randomIntArray(arraySize);

    Assert.assertEquals(arraySize, intArrayHolder.length);
}

@Test
public void randomIntArray_duplicate_value_check() throws Exception{

    int intArrayHolder[] = domain.randomIntArray(arraySize);

    Set<Integer> intSet = new HashSet<>();

    boolean isDublicate = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < intArrayHolder.length; i++) {

        if (intSet.contains(intArrayHolder[i])) {
            isDublicate=true;
        }else{
            intSet.add(intArrayHolder[i]);
        }
    }

    Assert.assertEquals(false, isDublicate);

}

@Test
public void randomIntArray_size_check_after_removing_dublicate() {

    int intArrayHolder[] = domain.randomIntArray(arraySize);

    Set<Integer> intSet = new HashSet<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < intArrayHolder.length; i++) {
        intSet.add(intArrayHolder[i]);
    }

    Assert.assertEquals(arraySize, intSet.size());

}

}
```

And I am being advised it is not good enough. Can someone point out where I went wrong?

Comment: Are you allowed to make use of `java.util` classes? You could simply create a list/set of 1000 integers in ascending order and call `Collections.shuffle()` to randomize the list/set. It's no more than 5 lines of code.

Comment: @GiantTree - that's a good suggestion, although `Collections.shuffle()` would need to have Object `Integers`, not primitive `int` values - though some 'simple' manipulations would get you there.

Comment: @rolfl alternatively a simple Fisher-Yates (swap) algorithm would do the trick.

Comment: @GiantTree, yes. Now, I see the point they are asking this --> Fisher-Yates (swap) algorithm
Simple short easy to understand.

Comment: @GiantTree - as an aside, I am almost convinced that [`Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) does not have 'shuffle' methods just so that teachers have something they can add to their courses ;-)

Comment: Your solution runs in infinite time - there is absolutely no guarantee that `Random.nextInt` won't decide to return `1` for ever and ever. Your code will never terminate...

Comment: @Boris the Spider - I do not quite understand what you are trying to explain. Yes, let's say to get a particular no e.g(1), it might take another 500 retry to get it. But not infinite. But if that is called infinite, I will learn it.

Please let me know.

Comment: @yas it's random - you might get the same number for ever.

Comment: @BoristheSpider yes got it. Thz

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your approach is *not incorrect*. It will get the job done (albeit, slower). If you want to improve your approach, keep reading. But first a few points on your code:

### Points on Your code

1. `intArrayHolder` seems a bit wordy to me. I believe `intArray` or even `array` would serve your purpose, without sacrificing readibility. Same for `randomNextInt`.
2. `for (int i = 0; i < intArrayHolder.length; i++)` is *redundant* because the length of `intArrayHolder` *will* be equal to `size` owing to the fact that you declared it like so. `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)` will serve you better.
3. Please note that `random.nextInt(size + 1)` **does  not return an integer between 1 and 1000**. It returns an integer in the range \$[0, 1001)\$, i.e. a number \$x\$ such that \$0\leq x < 1001\$. If you do a count, you will find that you are actually getting \$1001\$ elements. The extra number is \$0\$. To fix it, you must write `int randomNextInt = random.nextInt(size) + 1;` It is quite easy to understand: you just add a \$1\$ to shift the range from \$[0,1000)\$ to \$[1,1001)\$, i.e. the *correct range*.
4. `((!isDuplicate) && (randomNextInt != 0))` can  be shortened to `!(isDuplicate || ramdomNextInt == 0)`, by using De Morgan's laws. It would be even better if you flip the condition and force next iteration *before* adding the element to the array.
5. A general advice is to update the loop counter *only once*. People generally estimate the number of times the loop will execute by stealing a glance at the `for (...` statement. A `while` loop is preferred when the number of iterations is unknown or updation is irregular.
6. You seem to be using `snake_case` along with `camelCase`. The standard in Java is to use `camelCase`.

Therefore, the refactored code would be:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Domain {

    public int[] randomIntArray(int size) {

        Random random = new Random();
        int array[] = new int[size];

        int i = 0;

        while (i < size) {
            boolean isDuplicate = false;
            int randomInteger = random.nextInt(size) + 1;

            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (array[j] == randomInteger) {
                    isDuplicate = true;
                    break;
                }

            }
            if (isDuplicate) {
                continue;
            } else {
                array[i++] = randomInteger;
            }

        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

### A Better Solution

Your solution's best case running time is \$\Omega(n^2)\$. Moreover, as [Boris the Spider](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/22486/boris-the-spider) pointed out: *"... there is absolutely no guarantee that `Random.nextInt()` won't decide to return `1` for ever and ever. ..."* Therefore, it *might* be possible that your code never terminates (although it will be very unlikely). You can make it faster in the following manner:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Domain {

    public int[] randomIntArray(int size) {

        Random random = new Random();
        int array[] = new int[size];
        // populate the array with sequential values
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            array[i] = i + 1;
        }
        // "shuffle" the array
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            int j = random.nextInt(size - i) + i;
            // swap
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

It's running time is *linear* i.e. \$\Theta(n)\$<sup>1</sup>. I am basically describing the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

### Some Background Info: The Big-O stuff

The *Big-O* notation is used to define an upper limit of the number of operations executed (the maximum running time, in simpler terms). For example, if the exact number of iterations based on a given parameter (like the number of elements, digits, etc) called \$n\$ is
$$2n^2+3n-4$$
we can say that a reasonable upper limit is \$3n^2\$. In the Big-O notation, the constant term gets absorbed. When we represent this in the Big-O notation, we say: *"the (maximum) running time is proportional to* \$O(n^2)\$".

People tend to forget the other two notations: the *Big-Omega* (\$\Omega\$) and the *Big-Theta* (\$\Theta\$) The former defines a lower limit and the latter is the Big-O and the Big-Omega combined together. In the example above, the lower limit can be \$2n^2\$. Absorbing the constant, we say:*"the (minimum) running time is proportional to* \$\Omega(n^2)\$". The function can therefore be bounded within both upper and lower limits, or *both* the upper and the lower limits are in the order of \$\Theta(n^2)\$.

Your code has no upper limit. It only has a lower limit. So, only the \$\Omega\$ is defined for your code (unless we set out to do a lengthy mathematical analysis of the behaviour of the `nextInt()` function).

I suggest that you read the related Wikipedia articles. (I didn't cover \$o, \omega\$ and \$\theta\$, that's your homework). Remember, [Google](http://www.google.com) is your friend!

---

<sup>1</sup> Assuming that the `nextInt()` method takes \$O(1)\$ (i.e. *constant*) time to execute.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not fluent with Java, I'll let you complete what is commented in this code.

```
int intArrayHolder[] = new int[size];
int randomNextInt = /* generate a number between 1 and 1000 */;

// Fill the array with ordered values
for (int i = 0; i < intArrayHolder.length; ++i) {

    while (/* intArrayHolder[randomNextInt] is already set */) {
        randomNextInt = (randomNextInt + 1) % 1000 + 1; // Or you can generate another random number, but it will take a lot longer
    }

    intArrayHolder[randomNextInt] = i;

    randomNextInt = /* generate a number between 1 and 1000 */;
}
```

In your code, if your array is filled with 999 values, you have 1/1000 chances to generate the only value possible left. This can take a huge amount of time to find the last possible value.
The more your array gets filled, the more time it will take to place the next value.

This code will only generate 1000 random numbers, instead of generating another random number each time a duplicate is found.

Also, the variable `i` is not used to determine where we will place the random value, but it contains the value to be placed in the array.
This simplifies the way you can handle collisions (this way, you are not forced to generate another random value at each collision).

Comment: This seems over complicated. The standard approach is 1) generate ordered numbers 2) shuffle.